# HTML Entities Conversion

Tags: php, html, entities

I am storing data in mysql as follows

```
test &lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;asdaDSFDASfsafsaf&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;test&lt;b&gt;sadasdsadsads&lt;font color=&quot;#553333&quot;&gt;sadfsaFDASFSAFSAF&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br&gt;
```

I want to show this in browser using php.I used `html_entity_decode($sql[0]);` but the result I got is

```
test<br><br>..............
```

Expected result should be :

```
test



SAHJGJHGJH
```

Comment: You should not be storing double-HTML-escaped data.  In particular, you probably have XSS vulnerabilities.

Comment: And you are simply viewing this in the browser? Or using "view source"?

Comment: @MarkBaker: The former.

Comment: @SLaks - I know that, you know that - just trying to make sure that OP knows he shouldn't be doing that

Comment: any reason you're storing the html in sql as opposed to retrieving it in php?  You're mixing your design and data layers together.  This is almost always a bad idea.